# QueryStatus for command text in Visual Studio's SUIHostCommandDispatcher

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

Visual Studio exposes the [`SUIHostCommandDispatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.suihostcommanddispatcher.aspx) service to expose an instance of `IOleCommandTarget` that can be used to `QueryStatus` or `Exec` a command, given a GUID and an ID.

If I call `QueryStatus` with `OLECMDTEXTF_NAME`, I would expect to receive the name of the command being queried. While the call succeeds (returns 0 and updates the `OLECMDF` flags), the text is always empty. It's being successfully updated - if I pass text in, it's truncated.

Does anyone know why Visual Studio doesn't get the command's display name?